# C: Manipulating structs in separate functions

Tags: c, struct

I'm not sure if this is appropriate for this kind of forum, as it is a very specific question, but I'll ask anyway.

I have three files:

1. `main.c`
2. `functions.c`
3. `functions.h`

In `functions.c` and `functions.h` I have created a `struct`, and defined it as a type called `control`:

```
typedef struct
{
    char cUp, cLeft, cDown, cRight
} control;
```

I created an instance of `control`, and initialized the instance called `Keys` right at the beginning of `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main()
{
    control Keys = {'w', 'a', 's', 'd'};

    //...
}
```

I passed `Keys` into a function called `options_f`, which takes a `control` as its parameter and returns a `control`. The function prototype is placed in `functions.h`:

```
//in functions.h:
control options_f(control Keys);

//in main.c:
Keys = options_f(Keys);
```

`options_f` is located in `functions.c` and looks like this:

```
control options_f(control Keys)
{
    system("cls");

    printf("\nENTER | Place your symbol.\n\n1| %c |Move up.\n\n2| %c |Move left.\n\n3| %c  |Move down.\n\n4| %c |Move right.\n", Keys.cUp, Keys.cLeft, Keys.cDown, Keys.cRight);
    printf("\n\nTo change the keys: NUMBER,SYMBOL (enter 0 to return to menu).\n\n");

    int iTemp = 0;
    char cTemp = '\0';
    scanf("%i,%c", &iTemp, &cTemp);

    switch(iTemp)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            Keys.cUp = cTemp;
            Keys = options_f(Keys);
            break;
        case 2:
            Keys.cLeft = cTemp;
            Keys = options_f(Keys);
            break;
        case 3:
            Keys.cDown = cTemp;
            Keys = options_f(Keys);
            break;
        case 4:
            Keys.cRight = cTemp;
            Keys = options_f(Keys);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please enter a number from 1-4.");
            stop_f(2);
            options_f(Keys);
            break;
    }
}
```

The function allows me to change the contents of the characters in `Keys`. After having entered `0` and returning to the menu I called `options_f` again. Only it changed the values stored in `Keys`'s characters to some garbage values.

Why is that?

If you need more information on other functions I used, please ask.
I'm sorry if this seems very low level and stupid to you, but I'm trying to learn, which is why I'm asking.

Thanks :)

Comment: Just pass `Keys` in as a pointer. `void options_f( control* keys ){...}` and call it like `options_f( &Keys );`

Comment: Is there any advantage in passing it as a pointer, except for speed?

Comment: It is just a difference in logic. Using `control options_f( control keys )` reads (to me) as `options_f` _uses_ `keys` to create a new `control` while `void options_f( control* keys )` reads more as `options_f` modifies `keys`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a value from the `options_f()` function (probably `return Keys;`). This isn't even valid C code.

Comment: Right! Man I totaly missed that ^^

Thanks so much!